# DB2 restore on a databse with different table structure

Tags: database, db2

In current release of my application, I am planning to provide some updates for existing table.
If some user try to take a restore of data which they took backup before the new release. How the existing data will fit the updated tables?

How to handle this situation?

Comment: One general approach I have seen used to have both a roll forward and roll back script for each non trivial change to the database.  To make the current data fit going backwards, you might have to truncate some columns, etc.

Comment: I would like to discuss this in detail. For example user is on 2016 release and then he plans to take 2018 release. So, he will follow all the changes and scripts will take care of data base structures. So, no problem with the running system. But, user take a database backup before taking the new release, to be on safe side. Now, new release has changed the structure of table and user want to take a restore of backup. How this will work?

Comment: Consider the database structure (all the DDL, all the security, all the external objects) as having a *version* in the change-control sense. The database-version matches a specific release of the coded applications. If a backup-image of a *previous version* of the database gets restored, then that database must be migrated to whatever code version is currently installed. So the database-versioning tooling (database evolution) has to be able to cope with that.